# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute , even when i create a copy of the current object

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the following repository method :-

```
public void DeleteVM(int id, string username)
        {
            var VM = tms.TMSVirtualMachines.SingleOrDefault(a => a.TMSVirtualMachineID == id);
            var auditinfo = IntiateTechnologyAudit(tms.AuditActions.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "DELETE").ID,
                    VM.Technology.TechnologyType.AssetTypeID,
                 username, VM.TMSVirtualMachineID);
            var technology = tms.Technologies.SingleOrDefault(a => a.TechnologyID == id);
            technology.IsDeleted = true;
            tms.Entry(technology).State = EntityState.Modified;
            var vm2 = VM;
            foreach(var ip in vm2.Technology.TechnologyIPs)
            {
            tms.TechnologyIPs.Remove(ip);

            }
            tms.TMSVirtualMachines.Remove(VM);
                      InsertOrUpdateTechnologyAudit(auditinfo);
        }
```

But i am getting the following exception :-

> System.InvalidOperationException was caught   HResult=-2146233079
>   Message=Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not
>   execute.   Source=System.Core   StackTrace:
>          at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()

although i have created a copy of the VM and i perform the foreach over it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a **shallow copy**, not a **reference copy**. Even though you copy it over, you only copy the reference, so you're enumerating over the same `HashSet` as the one you're deleting stuff from anyways.
What you need to do is construct another enumerable, like a `List<T>`, over that. Like so:

```
var vm2 = new List<YourType>(VM.Technology.TechnologyIPs);
foreach(var ip in vm2)
{
    tms.TechnologyIPs.Remove(ip);
}
```

Comment: but in my case the VM is not a list it is a single entity.TMSVirtualMachines ?